# Importing a building into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, qgis-3

Given an SVG drawing of a building, and 2 GPS-reference points, as well as where north is in the drawing, how can I import a building into QGIS so the 2 GPS-reference-points are at the same coordinates  ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [edit] the question to specify the exact version of QGIS in use and to remove the incorrect version tag, as appropriate to the version in use.

Comment: Look at QGIS Georeferencer.